# hello i was trying to install postgis to one of my database with the following command CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-14, postgis-installation

CREATE EXTENSION postgis; but it returned an error of  ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/Library/PostgreSQL/13/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

i'm on mac OS

Postgresql 14 and PGadmin 4 and have installed Postgis with Brew

please help me out guys

Comment: How did you install Postgres?

Comment: have solved it thanks so much, i uninstall postgis the install it with stackbuilder.. thanks